# Re-arranging Equation with Integer Division

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have an equation that uses integer division (for calculating days in a number of months):

$x=30m
+\left\lfloor \frac{m+10}{11} \right\rfloor
+\left\lfloor \frac{m+8}{11} \right\rfloor
+\left\lfloor \frac{m+6}{11} \right\rfloor
+\left\lfloor \frac{m+5}{11} \right\rfloor
+\left\lfloor \frac{m+3}{11} \right\rfloor
+\left\lfloor \frac{m+1}{11} \right\rfloor
$

where $m$ is an integer in the range $0 \leq m \leq 11$. The year is taken to start at March 1st. So m=1 results in x=31 (Days in march), m=2 results in x=61 (days in March+April) and so on up to m=11 resulting in x=337 (Days in March through Dec plus Jan).

I was wondering how do you re-arrange the equation to solve for $m$? Re-arranging the equation normally does not work because it will end up containing $\frac{10+8+6+5+3+1}{11} = 3$, where as the integer division can make the fractional parts sum to as low as zero.

Comment: I think you're trying to pack too much into one formula. And I doubt the correctness anyway. $m = 0$ yields $0$; $m = 1$ yields $31$, $m = 2$ yields $61$. So I don't really understand what those numbers mean. (January has 31 days which corresponds to $m = 1$, first month; February has 28 or 29 days, but $m = 2$ doesn't correspond to the number of days at the end of February in either case).

Comment: The year is taken to start at March 1st. So m=1 results in x=31 (Days in march), m=2 results in x=61 (days in March+April) and so on up to m=11 resulting in x=337 (Days in March through Dec plus Jan). I am confident it works in that direction. But I don't understand how to go backwards, from x (number of days) back to a month (0 to 11).

Comment: @rubik what I meant was that the divisions ignore their remainder. So that 10/11 = 0, 11/11 = 1, 12/11 = 1.

Comment: I think you're missing " $+\left\lfloor \frac{m+0}{11} \right\rfloor$ " for the $31$ days in January. Also if you changed all denominators from $11$ to $12$ and increased the addition constants by $1$ also, you could add  " $-2\left\lfloor \frac{m+0}{12} \right\rfloor$ " to count a normal February also.

Comment: In my formula the months are March to Feb for m = 0 to 11 respectively. This is so that it works for both leap years and non leap years. Anyway that part is not really relevant. What I am wondering is how you do the formula back the other way, considering that the division is all interest division (that is the result of all divisions round down to the nearest int).

Answer (score 0):

A suitable reverse function to return which month $m$ a particular given day $d$ is in, returning $m=1$ for March etc. can take advantage of the regular near-alternation of the longer and shorter months:
$$m=\left \lfloor \frac{d-0.5}{30.6}+1 \right\rfloor$$

where $\lfloor\cdot\rfloor$ rounds down to the nearest integer.

Comment: The problem with that is July/August does not alternate, they are both 31. So it fails from 1st August. However I have figured out that since average days is 30.6, and there is a need to remove rounding error, so multiple that by 5 to get 153. Then the first month (march) has 31 days, not 30, so add two, this results in: $$m=\left \lfloor \frac{5d + 2}{153} \right\rfloor$$ , m=0 for march, 1 for april and so on. unto 11 for feb. This also means my original equation can simplify down to $$d = \left \lfloor \frac{153m + 2}{5} \right\rfloor$$

Comment: Just to calarify, the two is from (31-30.6)*5= 2, since the first month needs to start at 31, not 30.6.